# FlashBuilder generated swf files are different

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am using FlashBuilder to create flash file to show video.  Please see the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="1280" minHeight="720">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements here, for example, services and value objects -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import org.osmf.net.StreamingURLResource; import org.osmf.net.FMSURL;
            protected function vp_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent): void
            {
                var myURL:StreamingURLResource = new StreamingURLResource("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
                myURL.urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance = true;
                myVideoPlayer.source = myURL;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VideoPlayer id="myVideoPlayer" autoPlay="true" preinitialize="vp_preinitializeHandler(event)"  x="2" y="2"  height="100%" width="100%" />
</s:Application>
```

After clicking Menu >> Project >> "Export Release Build", FlashBuilder generates a swf file, which looks fine.  However, I found that the swf file changed EVEN IF I did not change any code.  This means, same code generates different swf files in each "Export Release Build" click.  I used command line fc to compare the generated swf files and confirmed each file is different.

I installed FlashBuilder of the newest version (ver 4.7 from Adobe). I wonder why the same code generates different swf files, and what kind of information is included in those different swf files.

Comment: Have you tried diffing the files? It could be something trivial like a build datetime.

Comment: Many compilers include metadata that changes with each build, like @pvg said.  You can try using a Flash decompiler to compare builds if this really matters, or do a binary file compare.  Or ask Adobe  :)  (or Adobe forums)